# How to recover data from flash or fully formated mobile?

Tags: data-recovery, mobile-data, data-transfer

My mobile was dead in warranty period, but after repair from service center I lost my all data.
Is there is any way to recover data from flashed Mobile. Suggest methods with computer or without computer. Is there is any app For mobile like esus for mobile.?

Comment: Did they replace the mainboard or logic board? If so, the storage chip has been replaced and your data was and is not on the current storage chip.

Comment: @GiantTree No they just reinstall os.

Comment: Did you enable encryption? This may prevent you from other ways to recover data. Is your device rooted? This is also a prequisite to gain full device access (needed to recover any data at all).

Comment: @GiantTree No. I wasn't encrypt my device. It's gr8 hope.

Comment: Is your device rooted? This seems like a way to recover data:https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-internal-memory-data-recovery-yes-t1994705

Comment: @GiantTree No rooted device.